# how to validate the textbox value from a table (grid) using jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to validate the text box value from the generated html table (grid) when the save button was clicked. The below is what I have so far. I traced the code using Firebug, it loops only the first row, but I need to loop the rows that starts from the second row within  tag. Any help please.

Html Code

```
<div class="msg-body">
     <table class="dynamictable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="display: none"></th>
                        <th>Package Name</th>
                        <th>Package Cost</th>
                        <th>No. of Attendees</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                 <tr class="prototype">
                        <td style="display: none"><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="" class="id" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="packagename[]" value="" class="pkname" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="packagecost[]" value="" class="pkcost"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="noofattendees[]" value="" class="nfattendees"/></td>
                        <td>@Html.ActionImage("", null, "~/Content/Images/delete.gif", "Delete", new { @class = "deleterows" }) </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td style="display: none"><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="" class="id" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="packagename[]" value="" class="pkname" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="packagecost[]" value="" class="pkcost"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="noofattendees[]" value="" class="nfattendees"/></td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionImage("", null, "~/Content/Images/delete.gif", "Delete", new { @class = "deleterows" }) </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
    </table>
     <div style="padding:20px 0 20px 100px "><input type="button" id="btnAddButton" value="Add New" class="button addbutton"/><input type="button" id="btnSaveRow" value="Save" class="button addbutton"/></div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code

```
 $("#btnSaveRow").click(function () {
        $('.dynamictable tr').each(function () {
            var $val = $("input[type='input']").val();
            if ($val == "") {
                alert("Please enter data");
                $(this).focus();
                return false;
            }
              return true;
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#btnSaveRow").click(function() {
    $("input[type='text']", ".dynamictable tbody tr:gt(0)").each(function() {
        if (!$.trim(this.value)) {
            alert("Please enter data");
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/QStkd/180/)**

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need it to start the loop from the second row not on the first row. The first row should not be validated because it was hidden, it is only used to clone the row.  How to do this one?

Comment: is there a way to pass the textboxes data to the controller?

Comment: @user335160 you can try with ajax